# Mutate with function error: "numerical expression has <n> elements: only the first used"

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use a custom function in a data frame that combines the values of two columns and add this to a third column in the data frame.

For adding a column I use mutate and it works perfectly e.g. if I sum up two columns or so but with a custom function I get this error:

> numerical expression has 32 elements: only the first used

The function is as follows:

```
 SigSum <- function(x,y) {
  result <- 0
  for(i in c(0:(x-1)))
  {
    result <- result + (1/factorial(i)) * y^i
  }
  return(result)
}
```

As an example I tried it with `mtcars`:

```
> bla <- mtcars  %>% mutate(bbb = SigSum(gear, carb))
Warning message:
In 0:(x - 1) : numerical expression has 32 elements: only the first used
```

If I use e.g.

```
> bla <- mtcars  %>% mutate(bbb = gear + carb)
```

I have do not get a warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Your function contains an error. Your for statement doesn't work with a vector input. You are asking for a loop of a vector of x instead of the length of the vector x.

if you change it as follows it will work:

Updated function:

```
SigSum <- function(x,y) {
  result <- rep(NA, length(x))
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    result[i] <- 0
    for(j in 0:(x[i]-1)) {
      result[i] <- result[i] + (1/factorial(j)) * y[i]^j
    }
  } 
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. With this function I don't get the error but it's not doing what I want. x and y are the numeric values of column X and Y in my dataframe (or gear and carb in mtcars).

Comment: The mathematical function should be: Sum(from i=0 to x-1)(1/i! * y^i)

Comment: I don't understand this. x is the value in a column, e.g. 4. length(x) then is always 1 so the loop will only be run once and this doesn't make sense...

Comment: the length(x) is the length of the vector you put in, not the value of the value of the vector. If you use mtcars$gear this will be 32, because there are 32 values of gear. The j will take the value of x[i], starting with value 1 to 32. So for the first value of gear, 4, j will go from 0 to 3. I also made sure the return of result is added to the returning vecort in the correct place. It was returning the results from the wrong loop.

Comment: With your function I get "Error: object 'result' not found"

Comment: My mistake. Adjusted. result was floating around in my workspace.